# "requestCursorUpdates is not supported" error with OutlinedTextField

Tags: android, state, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, data-class

I have several `OutlinedTextField` inputs, and typing into them does nothing while using a `Data Class` as the state holder in the `ViewModel`. Logcat returns the following `Debug` error each time I type a character from the softkeyboard. However, Logcat does not throw any runtime exceptions. How can I fix this?

```
W/RecordingIC: requestCursorUpdates is not supported
```

**Data Class**

```
data class ShoppingListItemState(
  val name: String = "",
  val category: String = "",
  val quantity: String = "",
  val unit: String = "",
  val ppu: String = "",
  val notes: String = "",
  val hasImage: Boolean = false,
  val imageUri: Uri? = null 
)
```

**ViewModel**

```
class ShoppingListScreenViewModel(): ViewModel() {

    val shoppingListItemState = mutableStateOf(ShoppingListItemState())

    fun setListItemStateValue(stateToEdit: String, stateValue: String) {
      val item = shoppingListItemState.value
      when (stateToEdit) {
          "Name" -> item.copy(name = stateValue)
          "Category" -> item.copy(category = stateValue)
          "Quantity" -> item.copy(quantity = stateValue)
          "Unit" -> item.copy(unit = stateValue)
          "PPU" -> item.copy(ppu = stateValue)
          "Notes" -> item.copy(notes = stateValue)
          "HasImage" -> item.copy(hasImage =stateValue.toBoolean())
          "ImageUri" -> item.copy(imageUri = stateValue.toUri())
      }
      shoppingListItemState.value = item 
   }
}
```

**CustomOutlinedTextField Call**

```
val shoppingListScreenViewModel: ShoppingListScreenViewModel = viewModel()
           
   CustomOutlinedTextField(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .onPreviewKeyEvent {
                    if (it.key == Key.Tab) {
                        focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Down)
                        true
                    } else {
                        false
                    }
                },
            label = stringResource(id = R.string.item_name),
            inputVal = shoppingListScreenViewModel.shoppingListItemState.value.name,
            isSingleLine = true,
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
                capitalization = KeyboardCapitalization.Sentences,
                autoCorrect = false,
                keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
                imeAction = ImeAction.Next
            ),
            keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                onNext = { focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Down) }
            )
    ) { shoppingListScreenViewModel.setListItemStateValue("Name", it) }
```

**CustomOutlinedTextField Composable**

```
@Composable
fun CustomOutlinedTextField(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    label: String = "",
    inputVal: String,
    isSingleLine:
    Boolean = false,
    maxLines: Int = 0,
    keyboardOptions: KeyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default,
    keyboardActions: KeyboardActions = KeyboardActions.Default,
    onValChange: (String) -> Unit
) {
    OutlinedTextField(
        value = inputVal,
        onValueChange = { onValChange(it) },
        label = { Text(text = label) },
        singleLine = isSingleLine,
        maxLines = maxLines,
        keyboardOptions = keyboardOptions,
        keyboardActions = keyboardActions,
        modifier = modifier
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. I had to do this instead:

```
fun setListItemStateValue(stateToEdit: String, stateValue: String) {
  val item = shoppingListItemState.value
  when (stateToEdit) {
      "Name" -> shoppingListItemState.value = item.copy(name = stateValue)
      "Category" -> shoppingListItemState.value = item.copy(category = stateValue)
      "Quantity" -> shoppingListItemState.value = item.copy(quantity = stateValue)
      "Unit" -> shoppingListItemState.value = item.copy(unit = stateValue)
      "PPU" -> shoppingListItemState.value = item.copy(ppu = stateValue)
      "Notes" -> shoppingListItemState.value = item.copy(notes = stateValue)
      "HasImage" -> shoppingListItemState.value = item.copy(hasImage = stateValue.toBoolean())
      "ImageUri" -> shoppingListItemState.value = item.copy(imageUri = stateValue.toUri())
  }
}
```

Comment: Is that how you got the logic to work? I have a similar error and I cant seem to find the issue with it.

Comment: @OEThe11 Yes, that's how I got the logic to work, and then I was able to  type into the `Textfields`. But, I think the error message was still there. What's not working in your app?

Comment: The search bar is not effecting my list at all. I have it set up. I can type in it, but it does nothing to the list. The list is stored in a data class that is connected to a room database. I do have my project on GitHub, would like to take a look at it and see how to get the search bar to work? I have been stuck on it for days. Thanks

Comment: @OEThe11 Sorry, as of now, I'm not familiar with search operations and wiring it up to the room database in a dynamic way. Maybe there's something wrong with the way you're calling the Textfield composable, or the way you're processing the search term, or how you're wiring up the search operation with the returned data from the room database. I suggest you create a SO question for this issue. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I added a ByteArray Field to one of my Room tables. Hopefully this helps someone.

Went from this:

```
@Entity  
data class FeatureXX(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id:Int,
    val input0:String,
    val inputImage: ByteArray
)

data class FeatureXXState(
    val initialStateInput0:String = "",
    val initialStateImage:ByteArray = ByteArray(0)
) 

sealed class ModifyFeatureXXEvent{
    data class EnteredValueInput0(val value0:String):ModifyFeatureXXEvent()
    data class EnteredImageValue(val imgValue:ByteArray):ModifyFeatureXXEvent()    
}

class ThisViewModel : VieModel(){
    private val _state0 = mutableStateOf(FeatureXXState(initialStateInput0 = ""))
    val state0: State<FeatureXXState> = _state0

    private val _stateImage = mutableStateOf(initialStateImage = ByteArray(0))
    val stateImage: State<FeatureXXState> = _stateImage

    fun onEvent(event:ModifyFeatureXXEvent){
        when(event){
            is ModifyFeatureXXEvent.EnteredValueInput0 -> {
                _state0.value = state0.value.copy(initialStateInput0 = event.value0)
            }
            is ModifyFeatureXXEvent.EnteredImageValue -> {
                _stateImage.value = stateImage.value.copy(initialStateImage = event.imgValue)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Composables were pretty much like yours.

What Solved My Issue ->

```
@Entity  
data class FeatureXX(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id:Int,
    val input0:String,
    val inputImage: ByteArray
){
    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false

        other as FeatureXX
        if (id != other.id) return false
        if (input0 != other.input0) return false
        if (!inputImage.contentEquals(other.inputImage)) return false
        return true
    }
    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        var result = id
        result = 31 * result + input0.hashCode()
        result = 31 * result + inputImage.contentHashCode()
        return result
   }
```

Then ->

```
data class FeatureXXState(
    val initialStateInput0:String = "",
    val initialStateImage:ByteArray = ByteArray(0)
){
  override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
    if (this === other) return true
    if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false

    other as F3TextFieldState

    if (initialStateInput0 != other.initialStateInput0) return false
    if (!initialStateImage.contentEquals(other.initialStateImage)) return false
    return true
    }
    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        var result = initialStateInput0.hashCode() 
        result = 31 * result + initialStateImage.contentHashCode()
        return result
   }
```

Finally ->

```
sealed class ModifyFeatureXXEvent{
    data class EnteredValueInput0(val value0:String):ModifyFeatureXXEvent()
    data class EnteredImageValue(val imgValue:ByteArray):ModifyFeatureXXEvent(){
    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false

        other as EnteredImageValue

        if (!imgValue.contentEquals(other.imgValue)) return false

        return true
    }
    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        return imgValue.contentHashCode()
    }    
}
```

No change to view model.